# Gitlab Cloud: Can't unprotect branch in project I own

Tags: gitlab

I was surprised to find that I could not force push to the `master` branch of a project I own on GitLab.
Also, there seems to be no way in the web UI for me to unprotect the branch.

How would you address that issue?

Comment: Are you using the right credentials (ssh key or GitHub user account)?

Comment: Yes, I can push, but I can't push -f.  Also, I see that the branch master is protected, but I can't figure out how to unprotect it.

Comment: Strange, GitHub has no branch protection, only BitBucket does.

Comment: Thanks - Gitlab, not Github.

Comment: Do you see a page similar to https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/411#issuecomment-11945896?

Comment: No, the UI has changed since then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug in Firefox. I am on a low screen resolution, and FF cuts off the "Protected Branch" tab.  This works on IE 11 (!!!!)

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/980

Workaround:  use full mode (press F11)

Answer (score 5):

You can protect and unprotect branches at Settings -> Repository -> Protected Branches [image: Settings -> Repository -> Protected Branches]

Answer (score 3):

That seems similar to [issue 8361](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/8361)

See [commit 68e35ea](https://github.com/cirosantilli/gitlabhq/commit/68e35ea99cef257ad34b926d7f83d09e650efc16):

### Make protected branch perms explicit in doc

> It was not very clear that not even the owner cannot force push or remove protected branches.

The author of that commit ([Ciro Santilli - `cirosantilli`](https://github.com/cirosantilli)) adds:

> To me at least [we could have the master branch not be protected by default, it's very annoying](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/6661354-make-default-branch-protection-an-option).
>
> As of 7.4, the default branch is protected by default.
> I'm sure that's great for many organisations who work that way, but now I have to unprotect the default branch every time a new project is added.
> I'd love to see a checkbox or setting somewhere that allows me to turn this behaviour on or off.

That last link includes a comment:

> You can unprotect the branch under project settings.

Comment: Thanks. Protected by default is one thing, not being able to unprotect it is something else entirely.

Comment: @The suggestion http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/6661354-make-default-branch-protection-an-option includes a comment I have added in the answer: would the project settings allow to unprotect that branch?

Comment: Thanks. It looks like a bug with the current interface: inability to unprotect a branch

Comment: @Jacko so the project settings page has nothing allowing you to unprotect the branch?

Comment: Yes, correct.  I see a label saying "protected", with no way of changing it.